# $2$nd degree inequality question

Tags: inequality, quadratics

If I have an inequality of the second degree, can I solve it using the quadratic formula?

Example:
$$-t^2+48t+100>500$$
Can i solve it by doing:
$$-t^2+48t+(100-500)=0$$
and apply the quadratic formula to it?

Comment: Yes, and then looking what happen between the critical points (roots and $-\infty$ and $\infty$)

Comment: From what I can tell of the zeroes/roots of the second formula, is that when the second formula is equal to 0, the first formula on the same values corresponds to the inequality criteria.
In the case of this exercise, they just want to know the $x$ values that the function is greater than 500.
I will have to give the answer in an interval form no? (Something like: $x>500$ for $]x_1,x_2[$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Either the graph will be positive between roots and negative elsewhere or vice versa. You can check that easily by putting any number except the roots(or even checking sign of limit to infinity)